# Erro ao setar modelo no JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, tablemodel

Então gente, estava desenvolvendo um frame que recebia uma tabela do banco de dados, usei o mesmo escopo da função várias vezes e ela funcionava perfeitamente, só modifiquei o necessário para gerar a tabela do jeito que eu queria nesse caso e começou a dar erro, já revirei o código procurando e até agora nada...

```
public JTable preencheTabela(JTable tabela){

    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String[] Colunas = new String[]{"ID", "Cliente", "Valor", "Data"};
    int i = 1;

        do{
            dados.add(new Object[]{"aaaa"+i, 
                "aaa"+i, "aaa"+i, 
                "aasa"+i});
            i++;
        }while(i<5);

    ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, Colunas);
    tabela.setModel(modelo);//Erro acontece nessa linha      
    for(i = 0; i<Colunas.length; i++){
        tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(150);
        tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setResizable(false);
    }
    tabela.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    tabela.setAutoResizeMode(tabela.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    tabela.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    return tabela;

}
```

Modelo Tabela:

```
public class ModeloTabela extends AbstractTableModel{
private ArrayList linhas = null;
private String[] colunas = null;
public ModeloTabela(ArrayList lin, String[] col){
    this.setLinhas(lin);
    this.setColunas(col);
}
public ArrayList getLinhas(){
    return linhas;
}
public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados){
    linhas = dados;
}
public String[] getColunas(){
    return colunas;
}
public void setColunas(String[] nomes){
    colunas = nomes;
}
@Override
public int getColumnCount(){
    return colunas.length;
}
@Override
public int getRowCount(){
    return linhas.size();
}
@Override
public String getColumnName(int numCol){
    return colunas[numCol];
}
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol){
    Object[] linhas = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
    return linhas[numCol];
}
```

}

Local onde eu invoco a função:

```
public FrmCancelaVenda() {
    jTable = ctrl.preencheTabela(jTable);
    System.out.print("teste ");
    initComponents();
}
```

Erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Controle.ControleCancelaVenda.preencheTabela(ControleCancelaVenda.java:43)
>       at Grafico.FrmCancelaVenda.(FrmCancelaVenda.java:26)

Answer (score 1):

O que houve foi que eu estava tentando modificar uma jTable que ainda não havia sido criada pela `initComponents()`, ou seja, apenas mudando a ordem de chamada da`PreencheTabela` o problema foi resolvido.

Sendo assim, pra se resolver o problema, seria necessário modificar o construtor pra que ele ficasse assim:

```
public FrmCancelaVenda() {
    conecta.conexao();
    initComponents();
    jTable = ctrl.preencheTabela(jTable);
}
```

Comment: @diegofm no caso responder na própria pergunta ?

Comment: Ah foi resposta? Ignore então :p

Comment: É que eu achei o erro, fiquei 2 dias procurando, burrice da minha parte...

Comment: @diegofm no caso de programas que tem vários arquivos, e no meu caso, um banco de dados, como eu poderia postar um exemplo minimo é completo do código?

Comment: Duvidas de swing, por ser a respeito de telas, são muito dificeis de analisar apenas com um trecho de código, e como você pode ver no link, demonstrar o erro atraves de um trecho isolado do seu código ajuda na resolução do problema, alem de aumentar a chance de sua pergunta ter uma resposta mais rapida.